# Method to stop QThread that calls OpenCV functions

Tags: python, qt, opencv, pyqt, python-multithreading

I have a simple PyQT application which, on press of a "calculate" button calls a long-running function that performs some image processing using OpenCV. To allow the GUI to remain responsive, the long-running function is executed in a QThread (I implemented this by following [this excellent Real Python tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-pyqt-qthread/).

Ideally, I would like to be able to cancel the calculation (e.g. by pressing a "cancel" button). Given that the function is busy executing in OpenCV, is there a "nice"/safe way to do this? Or do we have to resort to a more brutal and risky method to kill the thread?

Comment: The best would be if the opencv execution could be broken into as many as possible phases, and between the phases your thread can check whether it was requested to terminate (e.g. via a flag), and exit if needed. Anyway killing threads should be the last resort (if at all).

Comment: As addendum to @G.M.'s comment: the method which you can use to request interruption is QThread::requestInterruption() (you can call this from the main thread, it is safe) and then you can check it in the thread with QThread::isInterruptionRequested()